# Can users clear the keychain?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am trying to decided if I should store a value in the keychain or in AsyncStorage.

The value is a recovery PIN for backing up a private key. I want to set a local flag that the user has set a recovery PIN so that when the user re-opens the app I can decide to redirect them to set a recovery PIN or not.

As I see it, I have two main options:

1. AsyncStorage. Set a boolean flag locally with `AsyncStorage.setItem('isRecoveryPinSetup', true)`
2. Keychain. Store `Keychain.setGenericPassword(username, password)`

Pros Keychain

- Presumably keychain sync could be setup so when they login via a different device the PIN may be pre-filled for them.
- Keychain should persist between installs on the same device so the flag should be appropriately set after deleting and re-installing the app on same device.

My concern is that I'm not sure if the user has the power to clear the keychain data and what other considerations there might be.

Finally I could ask the server if they have a pin backed up but I would like to avoid that round trip if possible.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncStorage won't be useful at all. It will be cleared as soon as user remove the app but user wont be able to modify it until device is rooted.

Keychain should be best option. Keychain can be edited by user anytime but its very rare that user will modify it. At least i have never edited it.

Comment: Can you go into more detail how the user can modify it? On android vs iOS?

Comment: Keychain is for ios. User get the option to modify keychain in settings.